# wpf - LDAP always returns false when validating

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, ldap

My login window uses LDAP to authenticate users. However, when validating, it always returns false.

Here is the code for validation which I got from CodeProject:

```
public bool fnValidateUser()
    {
        bool validation;
        try
        {
            LdapConnection lcon = new LdapConnection
                    (new LdapDirectoryIdentifier((string)null, false, false));
            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(Environment.UserName,
                                   txtPassword.SecurePassword, Environment.UserDomainName);
            lcon.Credential = nc;
            lcon.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
            // user has authenticated at this point,
            // as the credentials were used to login to the dc.
            lcon.Bind(nc);
            validation = true;
        }
        catch (LdapException)
        {
            validation = false;
        }
        return validation;
    }
```

`txtPassword.SecurePassword` is the PasswordBox. When I enter my password/pin and hit login, it displays the MessageBox for whenever validation is false.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** The exception indicates "The LDAP Server is Unavailable", at this line `lcon.Bind(nc);`

Comment: Add a log to catch the exception, and what you got as an exception?

Comment: @Dinesh I've just added it

Comment: As per this exception, your LDAP server is turned off or not connected at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and found another approach for this, without using LDAP.

```
PrincipalContext adContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (adContext)
            {
                if (adContext.ValidateCredentials(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Password))
                {
                    MainWindow main = new MainWindow();

                    main.Show();
                    main.txtLoggedInUser.Text = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;

                    this.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password!");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var exceptionDialog = new MessageDialog
            {
                Message = { Text = ex.ToString() }
            };

            await DialogHost.Show(exceptionDialog, "RootDialog");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sample piece of code.

```
// the username and password to authenticate
const string domain = "OU=Organization,DC=mydomain,DC=com";
string password = "mypass";
string userName = "myuser";

// define your connection
LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection("ldap.mydomain.com:389");

try
{
   // authenticate the username and password
   using (ldapConnection)
   {
       // pass in the network creds, and the domain.
       var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);

       // if we're using unsecured port 389, set to false. If using port 636, set this to true.
       ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = false;

       // since this is an internal application, just accept the certificate either way
       ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };

       // to force NTLM\Kerberos use AuthType.Negotiate, for non-TLS and unsecured, just use AuthType.Basic
       ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;

       // authenticate the user
       ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
   }
   catch (LdapException ldapException)
   {
       //Authentication failed, exception will dictate why
   }
}
```

Comment: The domain and LdapConnection needs to be dynamic for when it is installed on the users PC. Should I replace the string with Environment.UserDomainName?

Comment: Try hard coding the value and make sure that is working fine then you can replace it dynamic value.